# Supporting multiple screen in Android without using multiple layout directory

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been developing apps for months and I've read that using `layout-small`, `layout-large`, `layout-xlarge` and so on to support multiple screen resolutions is `deprecated` started in `Android 3.0`(correct me if I'm wrong). Hence, I'm still using multiple `layout` directories but it's a lot of work when designing an Application.

My questions are:

- Is there any way to design a `layout` to support multiple screens all at once without using multiple `layout-size.xml` files?
- What is the alternative solution when using `layout-size` directory is deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

You can use dimensions. Basically, you'll have the same thing, with multiple directories, but for the `values` directory, thus a `values`, `values-sw600dp`, `values-sw600dp-land` etc.

In these, you can have a `dimens.xml`, with the following content:

```
<!-- In values/dimens.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="my_specific_dimension">150dp</dimen>
    //More items...
</resources>

<!-- In values/dimens.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="my_specific_dimension">150dp</dimen>
    //More items...
</resources>
```

You can now use `@dimen/my_specific_dimension` in a single layout file, for example for a width or a height, and it will use, just like for the multiple layouts situation, the correct dimension based on the screen category.

That works only if the layout is basically the same, with different sizes. There's little customisation with that solution. If you want to use different layout, you still have to write multiple layout files. I believe the deprecation of `x-large`, etc. was after they introduce `layout-sw600dp`, `layout-land`, `layout-sw600dp-land`. Check the documentation for [how to declare different layout for different sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts). It explains how to use the `sw<N>dp` qualifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not a standard layout that supports multiple screens.
For instance Normal layout can display with several inches, and accordingly may be among them some larger height or width. However, it should define be unique layout for each screen.